# Unable to properly step through code in static constructor (VS2019, C#, .NET 4.7.2)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to step through the code of a *static constructor* while in break mode.

The project is C#/.NET 4.7.2/64-bit/WinForms. Visual Studio version is 2019 16.9.4 Community.

Visual Studio correctly breaks when it gets to the breakpoint set in the static constructor. I can then step through the code using the "Step Into" command (F11). As you can see, the static constructor calls a static method which does the heavy work.

The code contains a loop that should iterate 10 times. I should be able to step through all iterations. Instead, after the first iteration, debugging suddenly jumps to -- or "resumes" -- at some much later point, back in the calling class (or more accurately, the class that triggered the CLR to execute the static constructor). So I am unable to step through the remaining 9 iterations.

I am confident that all iterations are indeed executed, because I added some debug code to print something every time the `finally` block is executed. But, I am frustrated that I cannot step through the code. Seems like a VS bug of the ludicrous kind, since it's a pretty fundamental thing to be able to step through code when debugging.

Because the problem is so hard to describe well, I have created an animated GIF to visually show the debug session:

[image: Visual Studio 2019 debug session example]

I have searched the web far and wide and I can't find anyone else reporting the kind of issue I am here. Which has me wondering whether I am doing something wrong (e.g. do I need to adjust some debugger settings or something?). Any help or insight is much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I cannot reproduce the issue in 32-bit Debug builds. The issue is (so far) only present in 64-bit Debug builds.

**HOW TO REPRODUCE**

I made a tiny demo project. Feel free to download and try debug for yourself. When the breakpoint is hit, use F11 to step through the code. See if you can get through the loop 10 times ;-)

[Debug Test Project (VS2019)](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ajsb8MXOJ6w_g6gFRTnDOzUVHu0LaA?e=MFZkdN)

On my end, the issue disappears if I change the build configuration from `x64` to `Any CPU`. So it may be a 64-bit only issue.

The `try/finally` block really seems to reveal the issue. I'm not sure what other patterns might reveal the issue too.

**BUG REPORT FILED**

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/The-debugger-does-not-step-through-a-met/1407274

Comment: Update: If I move the heavy code directly into the static constructor, then I *can* step through all iterations **but** I can't step through the `finally` block - the debugger just skips it entirely (although it does actually execute). What the h*** is going on?!

Comment: What happens if you put a break point inside the loop? Does it get hit 10 times?

Comment: @ekke Yes. If I set a breakpoint within the loop, the breakpoint hits 10 times. But, if I place the breakpoint at the `try` statement, then when it hits I can step through the code but then the debugger doesn't let me step through the `var` and `Marshall.StructureToPtr` statements - it skips those at every iteration! So strange.

Comment: @ekke A significant update - I cannot reproduce this issue in 32-bit Debug builds. The issue is (so far) only present in 64-bit Debug builds.

Comment: Sounds like it could be a bug, would it be possible for you to provide a small reproducible example project?

Comment: @ekke Absolutely. Are you able to guide me as to how I should make this project available to you and others?

Comment: Perhaps you could make a github repo? Or otherwise a zip with the project on a file sharing service, or even just a guide to reproduce would work :)

Comment: @ekke Done -  I have updated my question with a link to a ZIP on OneDrive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231568/discussion-between-ekke-and-michal-cihelka).

Comment: @MichalCihelka I can reproduce the issue on my end using your demo project. What a strange bug...

Comment: The animation reminds of the behavior when you have multiple threads and F11 suddenly jumps you to another one. I realize it's a static constructor so likely not the case but if you throw some debugs of ManagedThreadId or even look at the Debug->Threads window is it somehow jumping around?

Comment: This has made it into a github issue in the Dotnet Runtime repository: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/52328

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in the .NET runtime. You can track the bug here:

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/52328

Comment: Disable Just My Code option to avoid it